# how can I use this message to filter?

Tags: python

I print a value

```
clean_value <function cleaned_value at 0x00000225A60E4940>
```

from here

```
print("clean_value",cleaned_value)
```

and would like to filter with an if condition when clean_value is different from that message

how could I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to get a function's name as a string?

Comment: You can get the hex representation of the address for an object with `hex(id(cleaned_value))` which should be that `0x00000225A60E4940`. Then you can do whatever you like with it. The whole message is at `repr(cleaned_value)` and the name is at `cleaned_value.__name__`

Comment: What you want exactly?

Answer (score -1):

May you could add a little bit more of info, what's the content of your functions? are they built-ins ?

If they`re not builtins you could instantiate your function and print depending on conditions, for example:

```
def clean_value(value):
    return value

cleaned_value = clean_value(my_value)

if cleaned_value == "my expected output":
   print("other value")
```